# Binance oauth, where can i create a developer account for this

Tags: binance

-Been trying to get into binance [oauth](https://developers.binance.com/docs/login/web-integration). The doc didn't mention where can i get my client id.

Answer (score 3):

From the docs that you linked:

> *To begin, your application should identify the needed permissions (scope) firstly. Setup and register your application with Binance Accounts, and get your client_id . For now, please contact us.*

So according to the docs, there's currently no automated process and you'll need to contact Binance to get the OAuth2 `client_id` for your app.

Comment: i see, that's quite an odd way to get binance account. thanks!

Comment: @YauHongTan Oath (and the complicated process of getting the credentials) is in this case used for the identification of your *application* that wants to use the Binance Login. Not for the user account... If you want a regular user account (with access to most Binance APIs), you can go through their standard registration form.